# What is the name of the design pattern to avoid chained field access?

Tags: algorithm, design-patterns

There is a pattern or term that is used to avoid codes like

```
myObject.fieldA.fieldB.fieldC
```

something like this. I forgot what this term is called. Can anyone let me know about it?

Comment: Just to be sure, you are *not* including fluent interfaces?  Those can look very similar: `object.startItUp().andSomething().thenDoSomething().andCheckSomething().atTheEndProcessResults()`

Answer (score 0):

- It violates the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter), which states that code should only access its own local variables, parameters, and instance members.
- It could be a case of of [feature envy](https://elearning.industriallogic.com/gh/submit?Action=PageAction&album=recognizingSmells&path=recognizingSmells/featureEnvy/featureEnvyExample&devLanguage=Java), where a class calls a lot of getters or accesses a lot of data from another class.
- If these are really fields, they are poorly encapsulated (i.e., not behind a function), and any change to these fields forces you to modify all code that's using them.

Testing such code becomes hard, as you will have to mock not only `fieldA`, but also that's `fieldB`, and in turn that's `fieldC`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to create a new object and add certain properties to that object. If that is the case then it's **Builder design patten** where you seperate the construction and representation.

If you are trying to call a certain field with the above shown code then your design is very poor. An object should store only it's own properties.